# Como dar click a un boton web que no posee id, clase , tag, y tampoco name

Tags: html, vba, macros

Al Parecer la pagina https://laboral.pjud.cl/ tiene el botón consulta como imagen, pero no se como llamarlo desde `vba` hasta el momento cuando debía hacer algo como esto usaba `IE.document.getElementsByName("button")(0).Click`

Pero ahora no se que comando utilizar si alguien me puede ayudar, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Tendrás que llamar a la imagen y luego ejecutar su evento `onclick`, ya que si miras el código fuente, verás que sale `document.AtPublicoPpalForm.irAccionAtPublico.click();`

Answer (score 0):

En html5 puedes usar el atributo `[ onclick="function"`] en cualquier elemento

```
<img src ="src" onclick="function()">
```